# One Or Multiple Tables For Multiple Users

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a website where multiple users can register and post news articles, but I was wondering if all of the articles should go in one single table or if each user should get their own table. I'm guessing that the first option is going to be the simplest (and probably the best) but how many posts is too many for one table? I mean if all of the articles are fairly long, at what point does the site begin to slow down when using PHP to extract the data?

Also, similar to my first question, if each user can set multiple categories for their news profile, should all of the categories go in one table:

`table_categories : id, category_name, belongs_to (user_id)`

Or again, should a seppreate categories table be assigned for each user?

Comment: Use one table for all news articles, with a poster_id column linking it to your users..... too many posts for one table is far more than you'll ever need. mysql tables can handle thousands of millions of records as long as they're properly indexed

Comment: For the categories table, go with a single table again.... you'll have far more problems if you have a single table for each user

Comment: Yeah @MarkBaker I though a single table would be the way to go - I'm never expecting to get mullions upon millions of posts but it just made me wonder about how the big ones like Tumblr & wordpress.com go on getting thousands of posts per day

Comment: What is critical as the table grows is making sure that it's properly indexed for the queries that you run against it

Comment: Thanks again @MarkBaker. So would you agree with the answer below?

Comment: Yes, I'd agree with the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, you need 5 tables, one each for category, post and user, and 2 tables to store possible (many-to-many) relationship between user-category and post-category.

```
category - category_id, category_name, description
user - user_id, user_name, user_details
post - post_id, user_id, text
user_category_mapping - user_id, category_id
post_category_mapping - post_id, category_id
```

---

***EDIT***

If you want to have only one category per post, following four tables should suffice

```
category - category_id, category_name, description
user - user_id, user_name, user_details
post - post_id, user_id, text, category_id
user_category_mapping - user_id, category_id
```

Similarly, if you want to implement a subcategory functionality, you can alter the category table as below

```
category - category_id, category_name, description, parent_category_id
```

Comment: Well that makes sense in theory, but the category is defined by the user so wouldn't it be better to add `user_id` to the category table to begin with - Then the post gets assigned the `category_id` which can be reset to a default `uncategorised` if the user chooses to delete the category?

Comment: @user3177012 and what if a post has multiple categories? what if the same category (say rugby, football etc) is used by multiple users? What if you want to later suggest category to user?

Comment: That's where the `user_id` comes in right? I mean you would use in PHP `where category == football && user_id == $user_id`

Comment: Problem is, a post can be linked to any number of categories (one, none or many). Also, the user may have many categories, but every post may not be related to each of those category. How will you ensure these two in your model? Example, user has category `(baseball, football, world cup)`. He makes two posts, one for the `(football, world cup)`, another for `(baseball)`. How do you ensure that a post gets mapped to the right categories only? In my model you can, in yours, a post gets linked to all three categories even if 2 are applicatble.

Comment: Each post can only have ONE category. Remember this is a Category and not a Tag, so anything relating to `World Cup` would come under `Football` - Kind of like in a newspaper where `Football, Tennis, Golf, F1` all come under `Sport`

Comment: @user3177012 Ok, your last comment was not clear from your question, so I didn't think on those lines. In any case, having one category per post is quite restrictive, and a lot of news items can be filed under multiple categories, so are you sure of that?

Comment: I can see your point on how it might be restrictive but I don't think that sites like Tumblr let you have multiple categories (or any for that matter), they rely on tags don't they?

Comment: @user3177012 From [this wordpress support link](http://en.support.wordpress.com/posts/categories-vs-tags/), it seems that categories and tags are almost similar, though tags can be used much more liberally. Which means a post could have multiple categories, and many more tags.

Comment: So you're saying that there should probably be a `category` & `sub_category` in the categories table? I can see a way to make this possible but it might not be as straight forward

Comment: @user3177012 No I wasn't implying that, though you can easily do that using an extra column in the `category` table - `parent_category_id`.

Comment: @user3177012 I think the discussion has gone quite long already, and the question originally asked has already been answered, so think this over and maybe ask a fresh question if need be.

Comment: I've upvoted it but not accepted yet as I'm not sure if that answer shows the best way to go about it for my original question or blog. I'm still thinking of having one category for each article and then using the tags for specifics like `World cup` & `football` being under category `Sport` for example. I read this (http://www.problogger.net/archives/2008/10/03/how-to-choose-categories-for-your-blog/) which explains about not being too specific and having broad categories